# Javascript - setInterval, if checkbox checked then check radio alternately (no-library)

Tags: javascript, animation, checkbox, radio-button, setinterval

I want to present walking as a checkbox with radiobuttons. Every 2nd second there is 30% chance that the character begins to move, and 30% probability that it stops.
If the checkbox is checked it means, that the character is moving.
The second and the third radiobutton present the left or the right leg on the front of the character. I know that I make a big mistake by adding multiple setTimeout to the code.

So what I want to do is: If the checkbox is checked, the radiobuttons (2nd,3rd) should change its value alternately. If not checked, then check 1st radiobutton.

Is moving? [] Legs: ( *) | () ()

Is moving? [✓] Legs: () | ( *) ()

Is moving? [✓] Legs: () | () ( *)

Is moving? [✓] Legs: () | ( *) () ....

```
var move = document.getElementById('movement');
var leg = document.getElementsByName('legs');
var m;

function moving() {
    m = Math.random() * 10;
    if (m < 3) {
        move.checked = true;
    } else if (m < 6) {
        move.checked = false;
        leg[0].checked = true;
    }
    if (move.checked == true) {
        leg[1].checked = true;
        setTimeout(leg[2].checked = true, 500);
        setTimeout(leg[1].checked = true, 1000);
        setTimeout(leg[2].checked = true, 1500);
    }
}
setInterval(moving, 2000);
```

[- FIDDLE -](http://jsfiddle.net/kardaw/j3SqB/2/)

Comment: So if moving is checked, then every 0.5 seconds you want the legs to swap? Seems to me you need to just get rid of the *setTimeouts* and toggle the checkedness of the legs. You also need to cancel the interval if moving is unchecked so that every 2 seconds when you (possibly) modify its value, you can start and stop the "walking".

Answer (score 0):

I would set this up as follows. There's one interval that runs about every 2 seconds to determine whether to walk or not. Once walking starts, a second interval takes a step about every 0.5 seconds.

The first interval keeps running every 2 seconds and if it decides not to walk, it cancels the second interval and stops walking. If at a later time it decides to walk again, it starts the second interval again.

Hopefully the comments make it clear.

```
<script>

var walk = (function() {

  // Keep variables in a closure rather than global
  var moveBox, leg, m, walkInterval, i=0;

  return {

    init: function () {

      // Do setup, run every 2 seconds
      moveBox = document.getElementById('movement');
      leg = document.getElementsByName('legs');
      walk.stop();
      window.setInterval(function(){walk.start()}, 2000);
    },

    start: function () {
      m = Math.random() * 10 | 0;  // truncate for convenience

      // about 30% of the time, walk
      if (m < 3) {

        // If not already walking, start stepping every .5 seconds
        if (!walkInterval) {
          walkInterval = setInterval(function(){walk.move()},500);
console.log('starting to walk…');
        }

      // 60% of the time, don't walk
      } else {
         walk.stop()
console.log('stopped');
      }
    },

    move: function () {

      // If already moving, swap legs
      if (moveBox.checked) {
        leg[1].checked = !leg[1].checked;
        leg[2].checked = !leg[2].checked;

      // Otherwise, set to initial moving condition
      } else {
        moveBox.checked = true;
        leg[0].checked  = false;
        leg[1].checked  = true;
        leg[2].checked  = false;
       }
    },

    stop: function () {

      // Clear the interval if it's running
      if (walkInterval) {
        window.clearInterval(walkInterval);
        walkInterval = null;
      }

      // Set checkboxes to stopped condition
      moveBox.checked = false;
      leg[0].checked  = true;
      leg[1].checked  = false;
      leg[2].checked  = false;
    }      
  }
}());

window.onload = walk.init;

</script>


<table>
 <tr>
  <td>Is moving?<input type="checkbox" id="movement">
  <td>Legs<input type="checkbox" name="legs">|<input type="checkbox" name="legs">
                                              <input type="checkbox" name="legs">
```